# formatting JSON array output via

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am writing a small service in php to output a JSON string. The service is ultimately consumed by an Android JSONObject, if that helps. To keep it short, I have:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','myUser','myPwd') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('ctgscott_myDB') or die('Cannot select the DB');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM customers ORDER BY name ASC");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
$output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));    

mysql_close();
```

?>

The problem is the output arrives in the form:

```
[{"name":"Client Number1"},{"name":"Client Number2"}]
```

'name' is the column header for the name field in the 'customer' table and it is unnecessary for me to repeat it... I am struggling to format the output like:

```
{"name":["Client Number1","Client Number2"]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a multi-dimensional array instead. Try using this:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','myUser','myPwd') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('ctgscott_myDB') or die('Cannot select the DB');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM customers ORDER BY name ASC");

$names['name'] = array();
while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $names['name'][] = $e['name'];
}

print(json_encode($names));
```

Comment: Thanks, Christopher!  It looks like we are half way there.  The output is now:   {"name":[{"name":"Client Number2"},{"name":"Test Client"}]}

Comment: Sorry, let me clean that up:   {"name":[{"name":"Client Number1"},{"name":"Client Number2"}]}  Any other thoughts on pulling the 'name' out of the []?  The problem I have is that on the consumption side without extra parsing the Android JSONObject will take either a key/value or a key/array() pair.  Of course more work could be put in there... just trying to keep it simple on one side or the other. :)

Comment: Changing 'mysql_fetch_assoc($query)' to 'mysql_fetch_row($query) gave me: ...  {"name":[["Client Number1"],["Client Number2"]]}   ... so close.  Maybe i'll just go ahead with the parsing on the receiving side.

Comment: Sorry - thats my bad. I have amended the code above that should correct it.

Comment: Brilliant!  It works perfectly. Output={"name":["Client Number1","Client Number2"]}  ...Thanks Christopher!  Damn, I am new to StackOverflow and they won't let me 'up arrow' this question... boo.

Comment: finally became un-'New' enough to come back and up arrow your answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

here is good article to fetch data from mysql to android using php http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/. i hope you like it.